# Why is face_detection processing example not working?

Tags: java, opencv, arduino, processing

I am currently trying to follow [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/304) tutorial on face detection.
As far as my knowledge goes, I am sure my opencv dependencies are correct.
When I am running the face_detection example from the opencv processing example I get following error message:

```
Display -1 does not exist, using the default display instead.
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: processing.core.PApplet.registerMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
at hypermedia.video.OpenCV.<init>(OpenCV.java:297)
at face_detection.setup(face_detection.java:39)
at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(Unknown Source)
at processing.core.PApplet.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Is this just my webcam not being recognized? I do not understand the error message and some hours trying to get behind it did not get me too far.
I am using opencv 1.0 and processing 1.5.1.

Here the face_detection example code:

```
import hypermedia.video.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


OpenCV opencv;

// contrast/brightness values
int contrast_value    = 0;
int brightness_value  = 0;



void setup() {

    size( 320, 240 );

    opencv = new OpenCV( this );
    opencv.capture( width, height );                   // open video stream
    opencv.cascade( OpenCV.CASCADE_FRONTALFACE_ALT );  // load detection description, here-> front face detection : "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"


    // print usage
    println( "Drag mouse on X-axis inside this sketch window to change contrast" );
    println( "Drag mouse on Y-axis inside this sketch window to change brightness" );

}


public void stop() {
    opencv.stop();
    super.stop();
}



void draw() {

    // grab a new frame
    // and convert to gray
    opencv.read();
    opencv.convert( GRAY );
    opencv.contrast( contrast_value );
    opencv.brightness( brightness_value );

    // proceed detection
    Rectangle[] faces = opencv.detect( 1.2, 2, OpenCV.HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, 40, 40 );

    // display the image
    image( opencv.image(), 0, 0 );

    // draw face area(s)
    noFill();
    stroke(255,0,0);
    for( int i=0; i<faces.length; i++ ) {
        rect( faces[i].x, faces[i].y, faces[i].width, faces[i].height ); 
    }
}



/**
 * Changes contrast/brigthness values
 */
void mouseDragged() {
    contrast_value   = (int) map( mouseX, 0, width, -128, 128 );
    brightness_value = (int) map( mouseY, 0, width, -128, 128 );
}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add part of your code, including line 39, where the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the error:

> Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   processing.core.PApplet.registerMethod(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>   at hypermedia.video.OpenCV.(OpenCV.java:297)

It looks like this OpenCV Processing wrapper is calling's Processing's `registerMethod()` and the core library doesn't have it. It might be an incompatibility issue with the version of Processing you're using and the Hypermedia OpenCV wrapper. Bare in mind that this wrapper is pretty old now.

I recommend using [Greg Borenstein's OpenCV Processing library](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing) which you can easily install in Processing 2+ via **Sketch > Import Library... > Add Library...** and searching for **OpenCV for Processing**.
Once the library finished installing you should be able to run the [FaceDetection](https://github.com/atduskgreg/opencv-processing/blob/master/examples/FaceDetection/FaceDetection.pde) example.

Comment: Cool! Feel free to vote and/or accept the answer if it was helpful :)